# Efficiently replace text from column within large CSV

Tags: sql, powershell, csv

I have a large CSV file (1.7GB - I believe around 4 million lines). The file is a dump from Cisco IronPort of all traffic for a range. My end goal is to import the text into either SQL/Access, or one of the data modeling applications out there to be able to show browsing habits for the unique ids within the file (actually, 2 files).

Upon import to SQL, it bombs as one of the urls has a comma within it.  My idea was to try a rewrite on the URL column to dump everything after the TLD (foo.com/blah,tracking?ref=!superuselessstuff to just foo.com).

A coworker came up with the following two codes for PowerShell. The first one works great, but the 1.7G file drags my system to a crawl, and it never finished (ran for 48 hours without finishing).  The second one finished, but made the text harder to work with.  Help?

Source Data Example:

```
 "Begin Date"|"End Date"|"Time (GMT -05:00)"|"URL"|"CONTENT TYPE"|"URL CATEGORY"|"DESTINATION IP"|"Disposition"|"Policy Name"|"Policy Type"|"Application Type"|"User"|"User Type"
 "2013-07-24 05:00 GMT"|"2013-07-25 04:59 GMT"|"1374728377"|"hxxp://mediadownloads.mlb.com/mlbam/2013/06/23/mlbtv_bosdet_28278793_1800K.mp4"|"video/mp4"|"Sports and Recreation"|"165.254.94.168"|"Allow"|"Generics"|"Access"|"Media"|"DOMAIN\gen7@Domain 10.XXX.XXX.XXX"|"[-]"
 "2013-07-24 05:00 GMT"|"2013-07-25 04:59 GMT"|"1374728376"|"hxxp://stats.pandora.com/v1?callback=jQuery17102006296486278092_1374683921429&type=promo_box&action=auto_scroll&source=PromoBoxView&listener_id=84313100&_=1374728377192"|"text/javascript"|"Streaming Audio"|"208.85.40.44"|"Allow"|"Generics"|"Access"|"Media"|"DOMAIN\gen7@Domain 10.XXX.XXX.XXX"|"[-]"
 "2013-07-24 05:00 GMT"|"2013-07-25 04:59 GMT"|"1374728357"|"hxxp://b.scorecardresearch.com/p?c1=1&c2=3005352&c3=&c4=mlb&c5=02&c6=&c10=&c7=hxxp%3A//wapc.mlb.com/det/play/%3Fcontent_id%3D29083605%26topic_id%3D8878748%26c_id%3Ddet&c8=Video%3A%20Recap%3A%20BOS%203%2C%20DET%2010%20%7C%20MLB.com%20Multimedia&c9=hxxp%3A//detroit.tigers.mlb.com/index.jsp%3Fc_id%3Ddet&rn=0.36919005215168&cv=2.0"|"image/gif"|"Business and Industry"|"207.152.125.91"|"Allow"|"Generics"|"Access"|"-"|"DOMAIN\gen7@Domain 10.XXX.XXX.XXX"|"[-]"
 "2013-07-24 05:00 GMT"|"2013-07-25 04:59 GMT"|"1374728356"|"hxxp://lt150.tritondigital.com/lt?guid=VEQyNX4wMmIzY2FmZi1mMmExLTQ5OWQtODM5NS1kMjE0ZTkwMzMyMTY%3D&yob=1978&gender=M&zip=55421&hasads=0&devcat=WEB&devtype=WEB&cb=13747283558794766"|"text/plain"|"Business and Industry"|"208.92.52.90"|"Allow"|"Generics"|"Access"|"-"|"DOMAIN\GEN1@Domain 10.XXX.XXX.XXX"|"[-]"
 "2013-07-24 05:00 GMT"|"2013-07-25 04:59 GMT"|"1374728356"|"""hxxp://an.mlb.com/b/ss/mlbglobal08,mlbtigers/1/H.26/s93606666143392?AQB=1&ndh=1&t=24%2F6%2F2013%2023%3A59%3A17%203%20300&fid=0DDFB0A0676D5241-080519A2C0D076F2&ce=UTF-8&ns=mlb&pageName=Major%20League%20Baseball%3A%20Multimedia%3A%20Video%20Playback%20Page&g=hxxp%3A%2F%2Fwapc.mlb.com%2Fdet%2Fplay%2F%3Fcontent_id%3D29083605%26topic_id%3D8878748%26c_id%3Ddet&cc=USD&events=event2%2Cevent28%2Cevent4&v13=Video%20Playback%20Page&c24=mlbglobal08%2Cmlbtigers&v28=28307515%7CFLASH_1200K_640X360&c49=mlb.mlb.com&v49=mlb.mlb.com&pe=lnk_o&pev1=hxxp%3A%2F%2FmyGenericURL&pev2=VPP%20Game%20Recaps&s=1440x900&c=32&j=1.6&v=Y&k=Y&bw=1440&bh=719&AQE=1"""|"image/gif"|"Sports and Recreation"|"66.235.133.11"|"Allow"|"Generics"|"Access"|"-"|"DOMAIN\gen7@Domain 10.XXX.XXX.XXX"|"[-]"
 "2013-07-24 05:00 GMT"|"2013-07-25 04:59 GMT"|"1374728356"|"hxxp://ad.auditude.com/adserver/e?type=podprogress&br=4&z=50389&u=e91d539c7acb7daed69ab3fcdb2a4ea0&pod=id%3A4%2Cctype%3Al%2Cptype%3At%2Cdur%3A200%2Clot%3A5%2Cedur%3A0%2Celot%3A0%2Ccpos%3A3&advancepattern=1&l=1374710168&cid=1922976207&event=complete&uid=RzsxnCYcRkiQ6p9YxyRdEQ&s=e9c06908&t=1374728168"|"-"|"Advertisements"|"63.140.50.240"|"Allow"|"Generics"|"Access"|"-"|"DOMAIN\gen7@Domain 10.XXX.XXX.XXX"|"[-]"
```

First code that chews up resources, but spits it out as hoped, is this:

```
 $filename = 'Dump.csv'
 $csv = Import-csv $filename -Delimiter '|'
 $csv | foreach {
 $url = $_.URL
 $_.URL = $url -replace '^\"*(\w*)://([^/]*)/(.*)$','$1://$2'
 }  $csv | Export-Csv 'DumpParsed.csv'
```

Spits it out like this:

```
 "Begin Date","End Date","Time (GMT -05:00)","URL","CONTENT TYPE","URL CATEGORY","DESTINATION IP","Disposition","Policy Name","Policy Type","Application Type","User","User Type"
 "2013-07-24 05:00 GMT","2013-07-25 04:59 GMT","1374728377","hxxp://mediadownloads.mlb.com","video/mp4","Sports and Recreation","165.254.94.168","Allow","Generics","Access","Media","DOMAIN\gen7@Domain 10.XXX.XXX.XXX","[-]"
 "2013-07-24 05:00 GMT","2013-07-25 04:59 GMT","1374728376","hxxp://stats.pandora.com","text/javascript","Streaming Audio","208.85.40.44","Allow","Generics","Access","Media","DOMAIN\gen7@Domain 10.XXX.XXX.XXX","[-]"
 "2013-07-24 05:00 GMT","2013-07-25 04:59 GMT","1374728357","hxxp://b.scorecardresearch.com","image/gif","Business and Industry","207.152.125.91","Allow","Generics","Access","-","DOMAIN\gen7@Domain 10.XXX.XXX.XXX","[-]"
 "2013-07-24 05:00 GMT","2013-07-25 04:59 GMT","1374728356","hxxp://lt150.tritondigital.com","text/plain","Business and Industry","208.92.52.90","Allow","Generics","Access","-","DOMAIN\GEN1@Domain 10.XXX.XXX.XXX","[-]"
 "2013-07-24 05:00 GMT","2013-07-25 04:59 GMT","1374728356","hxxp://an.mlb.com","image/gif","Sports and Recreation","66.235.133.11","Allow","Generics","Access","-","DOMAIN\gen7@Domain 10.XXX.XXX.XXX","[-]"
 "2013-07-24 05:00 GMT","2013-07-25 04:59 GMT","1374728356","hxxp://ad.auditude.com","-","Advertisements","63.140.50.240","Allow","Generics","Access","-","DOMAIN\gen7@Domain 10.XXX.XXX.XXX","[-]"
```

The second code works markedly faster, but spits out badly formatted data, which SQL doesn't like.

```
 $filename = 'Dump.csv'
 Import-csv $filename -Delimiter '|' | foreach {
 $_.URL = $_.URL -replace '^\"*(\w*)://([^/]*)/(.*)$','$1://$2'
 Add-Content 'DumpParsed.csv' "$_"
 }
```

Not so pretty output:

```
 @{Begin Date=2013-07-24 05:00 GMT; End Date=2013-07-25 04:59 GMT; Time (GMT -05:00)=1374728377; URL=hxxp://mediadownloads.mlb.com; CONTENT TYPE=video/mp4; URL CATEGORY=Sports and Recreation; DESTINATION IP=165.254.94.168; Disposition=Allow; Policy Name=Generics; Policy Type=Access; Application Type=Media; User=DOMAIN\gen7@Domain 10.XXX.XXX.XXX; User Type=[-]}
 @{Begin Date=2013-07-24 05:00 GMT; End Date=2013-07-25 04:59 GMT; Time (GMT -05:00)=1374728357; URL=hxxp://b.scorecardresearch.com; CONTENT TYPE=image/gif; URL CATEGORY=Business and Industry; DESTINATION IP=207.152.125.91; Disposition=Allow; Policy Name=Generics; Policy Type=Access; Application Type=-; User=DOMAIN\gen7@Domain 10.XXX.XXX.XXX; User Type=[-]}
 @{Begin Date=2013-07-24 05:00 GMT; End Date=2013-07-25 04:59 GMT; Time (GMT -05:00)=1374728356; URL=hxxp://lt150.tritondigital.com; CONTENT TYPE=text/plain; URL CATEGORY=Business and Industry; DESTINATION IP=208.92.52.90; Disposition=Allow; Policy Name=Generics; Policy Type=Access; Application Type=-; User=DOMAIN\GEN1@Domain 10.XXX.XXX.XXX; User Type=[-]}
 @{Begin Date=2013-07-24 05:00 GMT; End Date=2013-07-25 04:59 GMT; Time (GMT -05:00)=1374728356; URL=hxxp://an.mlb.com; CONTENT TYPE=image/gif; URL CATEGORY=Sports and Recreation; DESTINATION IP=66.235.133.11; Disposition=Allow; Policy Name=Generics; Policy Type=Access; Application Type=-; User=DOMAIN\gen7@Domain 10.XXX.XXX.XXX; User Type=[-]}
 @{Begin Date=2013-07-24 05:00 GMT; End Date=2013-07-25 04:59 GMT; Time (GMT -05:00)=1374728356; URL=hxxp://ad.auditude.com; CONTENT TYPE=-; URL CATEGORY=Advertisements; DESTINATION IP=63.140.50.240; Disposition=Allow; Policy Name=Generics; Policy Type=Access; Application Type=-; User=DOMAIN\gen7@Domain 10.XXX.XXX.XXX; User Type=[-]}
```

Any other ideas?  I know a bit of powershell, and a little bit of sql.  But I'm open to anything else.

Comment: This is very hard to do.  For small files, the best way to import "real" csv (with text delimiters) is to use Excel -- but that is not an option on such a large file.

Comment: I've used a perl script to count the number of delimiters per line in a flat file, separating the proper lines from the problem lines. It processes around a GB/min if I remember correctly. That leaves you to manually correct the problematic lines, so it's effective so long as the problem lines aren't too common.  I'll post it in the AM if you haven't found a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First if you do this:

```
$csv = Import-csv $filename -Delimiter '|'
```

You load the whole file into memory as objects constructed from the fields.  So no surprise memory consumption and performance are an issue.  The second approach isn't too bad but it should be dumping out in CSV format. As it stands now, it dumps the contents of the objects that it creates.  You could try this:

```
$filename = 'Dump.csv'
Import-csv $filename -Delimiter '|' | 
    Foreach {$_.URL = $_.URL -replace '^\"*(\w*)://([^/]*)/(.*)$','$1://$2'} |
    ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInfo | Out-File DumpParsed.csv -Enc UTF8 -Append
```

BTW it would be interesting to see if skipping CSV processing would speed this up significantly or not e.g.:

```
Get-Content $filename | Foreach {$_ -replace '\"*(\w*)://([^/]*)/[^"]*"(.*)','$1://$2"$3'} |
    Out-File DumpParsed.csv -Enc UTF8
```

I'm just guessing on the log file's original encoding.  It could very well be ASCII.

Comment: +1 for a better explanation, but why do you convert object 'again' to csv, and just not export it ?

Comment: My original thinking was that Export-Csv was dumb and outputted only in Unicode which wouldn't be great for such a large log file.  But I see that Export-Csv does indeed support multiple output encodings.  So yeah, Export-Csv would be less to type.  And +1 for the more concise use of Export-Csv.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your second solution works faster because it does not put all the file in memory. You can try to change it like that :

```
 $filename = 'Dump.csv'
 Import-csv $filename -Delimiter '|' | foreach { $_.URL = $_.URL -replace '^\"*(\w*)://([^/]*)/(.*)$','$1://$2'; $_ } |export-csv 'DumpParsed.csv'
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a stream writer for your output? And instead of importing the file like a csv, just going through it line by line? Something like this:

```
$filename = "Dump.csv"
$out      = "C:\path\to\out-file.csv" # full path required here

$stream = [System.IO.StreamWriter] $out

Get-Content $filename `
    | % {
        $line = $_ -replace '\"+(\w*)://([^/]*)/(.*?)\"+','"$1://$2"'
        $stream.WriteLine($line)
    }

$stream.close()
```

If you're importing into SQL server, then there is a TextQualified field you can set to true, and it will treat everything inside quotes as a string, including the extra commas.

Answer (score 0):

If your database import chokes on commas, wouldn't it be an option to just replace that comma? Like this:

```
Get-Content 'Dump.csv' | % { $_ -replace ',','%2C' } | Out-File 'DumpParsed.csv'
```

Or like this (if other fields contain literal commas that you want to preserve):

```
Import-Csv 'Dump.csv' -Delimiter '|' `
  | % { $_.URL = $_.URL -replace ',','%2C' } `
  | Export-Csv 'DumpParsed.csv' -Delimiter '|'
```

`%2C` is the encoding for commas in URLs.